# Minimum and maximum values in feature scaling/normalization?

Tags: csv, machine-learning, normalization, feature-extraction

I'm fairly new to machine learning and I'm working on preprocessing my training data using linear feature scaling.

My question is, given a .csv file where each column of data represents a feature, with what minX and maxX values should I be normalizing my data?

More specifically, should I be normalizing each feature separately (using minX/maxX values from each column), normalizing all the data at once (finding minX/maxX from the entire dataset, ergo all the features), or normalizing on an input-by-input basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all of your features to be in the same range for linear classifiers (and not only them! Also for neural nets!). The reason why you want to scale should be very clear to you before moving forward. Take a look at [Andrew Ng's lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJmorz9gD4g) on this subject for an intuitive explanation of what's going on.

Once this is clear, you should have the answer to your question: normalize each feature individually. For example, if you have a table with 3 rows:

```
row | F1 | F2
1   | 1  | 1000
2   | 2  | 2000
3   | 3  | 3000
```

You want to scale F1 by taking its max value (3) and its min value (1). You are going to do the same for F2 having 3000 and 1000 as max and min respectively.

This is called MinMax scaling. You can also do scaling based on mean and variance, or follow another approach entirely by thinking that you usually have a "budget" in terms of computational resources and you want to maximize it. In that case, something like [Histogram Equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) might be a good choice.

A final note: if you are using decision trees (as a standalone classifier, or in a decision forest or in a boosted ensemble) then don't bother normalizing, it won't change a thing.

Comment: I understand normalizing feature by feature for the training data, but what about the input data I use when I start making predictions? For example, if I have an array of inputs: {F1: 12, F2: 19, F3: 8} should I be normalizing each value with minX/maxX values from the training data or from the other values in the array?

Comment: Of course. The classifier that you have trained is a function f(V) where V is your feature vector. If V was normalized through some other function g(V), then you need to apply the exact same function to the predict data. So for example if you use minmax normalization, you need to store what were the min and max values somewhere so that you can apply the exact same normalization to the predict data. Note: if your predict data has a feature that's smaller than the min or bigger than the max, simply set it to MIN or MAX (respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Normalize each feature separately. What you want is to limit the range of each feature in a well defined interval (i.e. [0,1]).
Use data from training data set only.

If you use Min-Max scaling you are going to have a smaller STD, this is not bad. If use Min-Max or standardization (mu=0, std=1) depends on the application you need to do.

Comment: Okay, so when I input an array of features {F1: 12, F2: 19, F3: -80} into my neural net, do I normalize each feature with past minX/maxX data (from the training data)? Or do I normalize it with minX/maxX values from the input array?

Comment: If the training data set is good enough your input data should be in the range [0,1] using the min-max from from it. If this does not happen it's not a good thing. Anyway use the min-max from the training data set.